# Why are my psd files shrinking when I open them in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm trying to open my `.psd` files in Adobe Illustrator, but it's turning them into really small files.

It's probably something to do with the advance settings, but I cant seem to find it.

Comment: what is the PPI of your Photoshop files?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you worried about the size and not the quality of the files in regards to color, palette, canvas, etc. etc?  Do you have any problems other than size?

Answer (score 1):

it could be that your psd files are not set to the scale you expected.
try opening them in photoshop, go to Image > Image Size and check that the size you intended.

Illustrator will always bring any placed image in at the size it was last saved at.

Answer (score -1):

It's normal
PSD files always look like pixelated, but they are not.
Export AI file (including psd file) in png or jpeg and you 'll see the original quality.